# Ionic v4 Play Store android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I'm uploading an ionic v4 application to play store and apk upload, I have this error:

- Your APK or Android App Bundle uses permissions that require a privacy policy: (android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE).

I've seen several ideas on how to work on native android, but not on ionic framwork.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. As it was my first app in the Play Store, I did not know the need to include the privacy policy in the google play console. ;)